# Data base export to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, export

I'm working on a website that has a data base (phpmyadmin) with several articles, what i want to do now is to put all off that on a remote server. I never did this with a website that has mysql, i tried this now and it seens it can't connect with the database ('Database error.'). So i have this code to do the connection:

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'username', 'password');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}
?>
```

It all works at 100% on localhost so i guess what it's missing is just the connection. Do I have to do something on this piece of code? if yes, What is it? and do I have to do anything else? plz explain like i'm a child. Thanks very much

Comment: Database, phpmyadmin ? Is your host localhost while you are on a remote server ?

Comment: I don't know, i don't think so, i have the domain already, what do i put instead?

Comment: Its depends from your hosting. Check in the documentation / Frequently asked question.